# WebView crashing on input when used with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When creating a dead-simple `WebView` wrapper with Jetpack Compose, the app crashes the second I enter any text. Is this a bug, or am I doing something stupid? The relevant code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WebViewC()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WebViewC() {
    return AndroidView(viewBlock = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            }
            loadUrl("https://google.com")
        }
    })
}
```

The crash:

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyEvent can't be processed because this key input node is not active.
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.key.KeyInputModifier.processKeyInput(KeyInputModifier.kt:62)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.kt:173)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchKeyEvent(AndroidComposeView.kt:177)
```

Comment: it only crashes for me if i use the keyboard on my computer when running on emulator - does the keyboard on the phone work for you?

Comment: I am seeing this on hardware phones too. App is using compose 1.0.0-alpha07

Comment: It should be a Compose bug. Not only the keyboard input, the webView crashes when we click the device’s Back button if the canGoBack=true. I got workaround for the back button issue, but nothing to do with the keyboard input case. Open the web page by external browsers if we really need to display a web page with input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this was in fact a bug in Compose. Updating to the newest version (`alpha09` at the time of this answer) seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to dynamic change url you need to add update method too.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) {
  AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(it).apply {
      layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
      )
      webViewClient = WebViewClient()
      loadUrl(urlToRender)
    }
  }, update = {
    it.loadUrl(urlToRender)
  })
}
```